# Why "\b" doesn't work in the regex pattern of find?

Tags: regex, macos, unix, find

I'm using the `find` command in Mac OS X 10.9, I tried commands like this:

```
$ touch "a gre a"
$ find -E . -iregex ".*\bgre\b.*"
```

It looks that the `find` will not return this file named `a gre a`.. Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`find` command's regex engine (ERE) doesn't support `\b` for word boundaries.

On OSX following will work for word boundaries:

```
find -E . -iregex ".*[[:<:]]gre[[:>:]].*"
```

Comment: You mean extended (modern) regular expressions doesn't include `\b` as shorthand, or `\b` is missing only in `find`'s ERE? Do you know how I can know whether a shorthand exist in a command's regex function.. Thanks very much!

Comment: I believe on OSX tools `\b` isn't supported in other tools like awk, sed also. I usually find online sited to looks for documentation on ERE since man paged doesn't cover it.

Comment: On other systems `\<` and `\>` are supported as word boundaries but OSX (BSD) has this weird syntax `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`